# How to position elements to look the same in landscape/portrait?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my elements to look the same in mobile portrait. Tried `@media screen and (orientation: portrait) ...` as it looks fine in landscape, but nothing changes.

Css:

```
 .awpcp-listings {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

 .awpcp-listing-excerpt 
 {
 min-width: 20%;
 margin-right: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 16px #888888 !important;
 border-style: solid;
 color: grey;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 flex-grow: 2;
 } 

  .awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner {
  min-width: 140px;
  min-height: 200px;
  }
 .awpcp-listing-excerpt-content {
 display: none;
  }
 .awpcp-listing-title {
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: yellow;
 }
 .awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
 margin-left: 20px;
 }
```

Tried all the above divs with `@media screen and` for example....

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {.awpcp-listing- 
excerpt-extra {
margin-left: 20px;
}}
```

Nothing.

Html:

```
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt $awpcpdisplayaditems 
$isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp- 
listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small": 
[328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
$awpcp_image_name_srccode
</div>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
<h4 class="awpcp-listing-title">$title_link</h4>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
content">$excerpt</div>
</div>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
$awpcpadpostdate
$awpcp_city_display
$awpcp_state_display
$awpcp_display_adviews
$awpcp_display_price
$awpcpextrafields
```

The `@media screen` should get it to display the elements side by side and on top of each other. In mobile landscape they do, in mobile portrait they don't.

Page is: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

Comment: you change `margin-left: 20px` to `margin-left: 20px`. what should change ?

Comment: The `@media screen` should get it to display the elements side by side and on top of each other. In mobile landscape they do, in mobile portrait they don't.

Comment: propably because portrait has less width then landscape and your elements wrap like `flex-wrap:wrap` instructs to do. I can see also that there are some breakpoints in your html, I don't know if its relevant and if it changes something but obviously its not full css. I dont think it matters if this is landscape or portrait, I think its more about width of the screen. You could prepare some jsfiddle, or make some images how it looks in both cases, would be easier to help.

Comment: OK. Youu mean. `@media (max-width.....} etc`?

Comment: I can't post images here can I?

Comment: Or if i delete `flex wrap`?

Comment: page is: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/